# make footer sticky with bootsrap + responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is my html and i can't seperate footer from container .
here is the **html**:

```
<div class="container-fluid fill-height">
    <div class="view-slide-in ng-scope">    
        <form id="signup-form" name="frm">
            <input type="text">
                <button>HI</button>
        </form>
        <div id="footer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom ng-scope">
        <div class="container col-md-offset-2">
        sss
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/6b0wkb5z/)
how can i make this sticky ?

Update:

**Normal**
[image]

**Resize**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the footer to be pushed off the bottom if the main content is too large for the page (rather than sitting over the content like fixed or absolute position would do), you can use the following styles:

```
body, html, .container-fluid {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.view-slide-in {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.view-slide-in > form {
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;
}
#footer {
    display:table-row;
    background:red;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6b0wkb5z/3/)

[Content pushing footer down](http://jsfiddle.net/6b0wkb5z/4/)

Comment: thx, i have many divs in .view-slide-in that are parents form,should i add height 100% and display table to all of them ?

Comment: but that's not responsive!! when i resize window, footer is in center of window

Comment: Sorry, was in a meeting.  Can you update the fiddle with the html you are using and I will see what happens.  Also, when you say center - is that vertical or horizontal center?

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute and bottom: 0.

```
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6b0wkb5z/1/

Answer (score 0):

why u cant use this..

```
<div id="footer" class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center">

            <p class="text-muted credit">here is the footer</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/e3ffem2r/)